# Jenkins failed to start

Tags: jenkins

I have a problem with jenkins which returned me a error when I try to enter.
Jenkins service looks correctly run.

```
Error
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:237)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:914)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:813)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:83)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:79)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:225)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:109)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:903)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:105)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /home/develenv/app/hudson/log/Audit Trail.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:165)
    at hudson.logging.LogRecorder.load(LogRecorder.java:314)
    at hudson.logging.LogRecorderManager.load(LogRecorderManager.java:101)
    at hudson.logging.LogRecorderManager.init(LogRecorderManager.java:196)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : input contained no data
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:126)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readRealEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:148)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:141)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.move(AbstractPullReader.java:118)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.moveDown(AbstractPullReader.java:103)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.<init>(XppReader.java:63)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractXppDriver.createReader(AbstractXppDriver.java:54)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractXppDriver.createReader(AbstractXppDriver.java:65)
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:163)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3003)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1410)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:109)
    ... 24 more
```

The file /home/develenv/app/hudson/log/Audit Trail.xml exists and is correct.

Any ideas?

thx

Comment: Are the file-permissions for the file correct?

Comment: File-permissions are correct for the jenkins user. This is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue with Jenkins after upgrading certain plugins.

I found the 'Build Graph View Plugin (version 1.4)' to cause this same exception you have described. I was able to fix this by downgrading the plugin to version 1.2.

If you do not have this plugin specifically, I would suggest downgrading your plugins one at a time until you find the culprit. It is most likely a version issue with one of your plugins.

One downside of the immense extensibility of Jenkins via plugins is obscure problems like these.